# Golang xml marshal appending items with deeper?

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I am going off an example here: 
https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-create-new-xml-file

What if it goes one more deep after Staff?

```
type Staff struct {
XMLName xml.Name `xml:"staff"`
ID int `xml:"id"`
FirstName string `xml:"firstname"`
LastName string `xml:"lastname"`
UserName string `xml:"username"`
Thing Thing `xml:"thing"`
}
```

How would I append? I've tried something like this:

```
v.Staffs = append(v.Staffs, Staff{ID: 108, FirstName: "Jennifer", LastName: "Loh", UserName: "jenniferloh", Thing.tape: "scotch"})
```

But only making two statements that iterate with the loop worked and its ugly:

```
v.Staffs = append(v.Staffs, Staff{ID: 108, FirstName: "Jennifer", LastName:    "Loh", UserName: "jenniferloh"})

v.Staffs.Thing[i] = append(v.Staffs.Thing, Thing{scotch: "tape"})
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Thing struct {
    stuff string `xml:"stuff"`
}

type Staff struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"staff"`
    ID int `xml:"id"`
    FirstName string `xml:"firstname"`
    LastName string `xml:"lastname"`
    UserName string `xml:"username"`
    Thing Thing `xml:"thing"`
}

stuff := Thing{Stuff: "120"}
v.Staffs = append(v.Staffs, Staff{ID: 108, FirstName: "Jennifer", LastName: "Loh", UserName: "jenniferloh", Thing: stuff})
```